# What is the correct way to accept all json field values as String in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and trying some hands on. Currently, I have a schema using which I load json data into Spark. The structure of the json is as follows:

```
{
   "value1": 345.2
   "value2": 32
}
```

I am using the following Schema to read this json structure:

```
val myJsonschema = StructType(
        Array(
            StructField("value1", StringType)
            StructField("value2", StringType)
        )
)
```

I am applying the schema as:

```
val dataFrame_val1_val2 = myDataStream.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), myJsonschema).as("data"))
```

However, when I check the contents of `dataFrame_val1_val2`, I am getting double values as `{"$numberDouble":"345.2"}` instead of just `345.2`. For integers is working fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

try to change schema type

```
val schemaJson = new StructType().add(StructField("value1",FloatType)).add(StructField("value2",IntegerType))

json.select(from_json($"json", schemaJson) as "value")
  .withColumn("value1",$"value.value1").withColumn("value2",$"value.value2").drop("value")
  .show( 5 , false)
```

Comment: I want to always capture as strings as the values for value1 and value2 are not consistent. So, I want to capture both of them as Strings only.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it’s not required to give the schema at all; Spark will infer the schema for you:

```
spark.read.json(“yourfile.json”).show
```